# Share Domain between Firebase and Hostgator

Tags: firebase, cross-domain, firebase-hosting

I am sorry if this is a dumb question, but lets say that I want to create a website using ReactJS and host it in Firebase, but at the same time I want to use the same domain of that firebase website in Hostgator where I will create an API to manage the database of this site, is this possible? I now that I can use firestore but I already have a PHP API.

Answer (score 0):

A DNS can send the traffic for a specific domain (a FQDN) to only one endpoint. There's no way to configure DNS to send traffic for a single domain to multiple destinations.

You have a few options though:

1. It is possible to create an endpoint that forwards the incoming traffic to other endpoints based on some rules that you define. This type of endpoint is known as a (reverse) proxy and they exist in many platforms. So you could set up your own proxy that determines where to send the traffic, and then funnel the responses back to the caller.
2. You can set up different subdomains for different purposes, and configure **those** in our DNS. Each subdomain is separate for the DNS, so you can point for example `hostgator.yourdomain.com` to Host Gator, and `firebase.yourdomain.com` to Firebase Hosting.